# NotSupportedException during the execution of Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(string email)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

Why I cannot execute the following code? (It throws the exception: NotSupportedException)

```
Membership.FindUsersByEmail(model.Email);
```

I probably missed some configurations, could you please indicate what should I have to do?

(I am working with a SimpleMembershipProvider)

Comment: You might already figured it out. If you are using SimpleMembershipProvider, you can use WebSecurity class. Its a wrapper around Membership.

Answer (score 0):

The simple providers do not support many of the old APIs, and will return NotSupportedException if called.
Unsupported MembershipProvider functions are:

- CreateUser
- GetUser (by providerUserKey)
- GetUserNameByEmail
- FindUserByUserName
- FindUserByEmail
- GetAllUsers
- FindUsersByName
- FindUsersByEmail
- UnlockUser
- ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer
- GetNumberOfUsersOnline
- GetPassword
- ResetPassword

You can find more details here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/637428/SimpleMembershipProvider-vs-MembershipProvider